# Unable to use new unified AWS CLI with ElasticBeanstalk create-application-version command

Tags: windows, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm attempting to use the [new(ish) AWS unified CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with command `aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version` and am unable to get the format of the `--source-bundle` argument correctly.

I've tried various formats and get similar errors each time. The commands are being run on Windows Server 2008 via Powershell. I am able to use the `aws s3 mb` and `cp` commands without issue so I do not believe it is an installation, Python/PATH, or Windows issue.

You'll see the `$builddate` variable which is defined in Powershell as follows:

`$builddate = Get-Date -format MMddyyhhmmss`

Commands I've tried and their errors

Command:

`aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name Api.Mobile --version-label Api.Mobile-production-$builddate --source-bundle build-production/APIv1/build-production-$builddate.zip`

Error:

`Error parsing parameter --source-bundle, should be: --source-bundle S3Bucket=value,S3Key=value`

So then I try the following command to adhere to the suggested format:

`aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name Api.Mobile --version-label Api.Mobile-production-$builddate --source-bundle S3Bucket=build-production/APIv1,S3Key=build-production-$builddate.zip`

Error:

`Unknown options: S3Key=build-production-022414101105.zip`

I've also tried the `S3Bucket=` declaration without the subfolder (even though the file does not exist without the subfolder) and still get the `Unknown options` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Powershell issue of parsing the comma.

From the aws-cli Github issue, answered by jamesls:

> I believe the issue is that powershell is parsing the comma character
>   out before the CLI sees the argument list.
>
> For example, the above command is split into arguments like this on
>   powershell:

```
['elasticbeanstalk', 'create-application-version',
'--application-name', 'Api.Mobile', '--version-label',
'Api.Mobile-production-', '--source-bundle',
'S3Bucket=build-production/APIv1', 'S3Key=build-production-.zip']
```

> If you surround the value in double quotes, then powershell leaves the
>   comma character alone:

```
$ aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name
Api.Mobile --version-label Api.Mobile-production-$builddate
--source-bundle "S3Bucket=build-production/APIv1,S3Key=build-production-$builddate.zip"

['elasticbeanstalk', 'create-application-version',
'--application-name', 'Api.Mobile', '--version-label',
'Api.Mobile-production-', '--source-bundle',
'S3Bucket=build-production/APIv1,S3Key=build-production-.zip']
```